# Configuring mysql in camunda wildfly

Tags: mysql, wildfly, camunda

I have run the table scripts in mysql and done all steps according to the following link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/O8dpppcvwt8

But this link has **apache** set up so the files where I have to edit the dependencies are not present in **wildfly**. Also where to set up the jdbc url and connections?

**Softwares I have**

- mysql-5.6.24-winx64
- wildfly-8.2.1.Final
- camunda-bpm-wildfly-7.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a mysql wildfly module and add the driver to the server configuration as described in this [tutorial](https://sheemoul.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/configure-mysql-datasource-in-wildfly-8-0/). You than have to adjust the configuration of the process engine data source like described in the [installation guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/installation/full/jboss/manual/#create-a-datasource).

Comment: The installation guide gives steps to install a process engine with h2 and when I click on "How to configure a MySQL database" it opens up [ironjacamar](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.0/en-US/html_single/?bcsi_scan_686bee1cf3c8ee0f=0#about). How do we add the process engine with mysql?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped a lot :D